# Clean logic to toggle depending on choice

Tags: jquery, toggle, onchange

So I've got a select field.

```
<select name="selection_group_1" id="selection_group_1" onChange="guests()">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
</select>
```

Notice the onChange. I use this to call a function instead of jQuery's $().change() just because i never have luck with anything jquery .click, .change etc... always buggy. But i'm open to using it if necessary.

So basically when a user chooses 0,1,2,3 I want to toggle divs. This setup looks like so.

```
<div id="guestNames" style="display:none;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr><td colspan="3">Please enter the guest names</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Guest #</td><td>First</td><td>Last</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="guest1" style="display:none;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Guest #1:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="text_field_5" id="text_field_5" style="width:70px;" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="text_field_6" id="text_field_6" style="width:70px;" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="guest2" style="display:none;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Guest #2:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="text_field_7" id="text_field_7" style="width:70px;" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="text_field_8" id="text_field_8" style="width:70px;" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="guest3" style="display:none;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Guest #3:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="text_field_9" id="text_field_9" style="width:70px;" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="text_field_10" id="text_field_10" style="width:70px;" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

div #guestNames should show by default as long as it's not 0.
The remaining divs #guest1, #guest2, #guest3 should show like this...
if(1) - show div #guest1
if(2) - show #guest1 and #guest2
if(3) - show #guest1 and #guest2 and #guest3
if(0) - hide it all.

Now i can do this my way, but i'm a jquery nooblet and my way is long cumbersome and the logic isn't even foolproof. Originally i tried using .toggle() however that didn't work so well when i chose 2, than 1 would hide and 2 would show... it was always dependent on my first choice. Than i tried checking .css("display"), but that was just a longer version that also caused the same issue.

So what I really need help with doing and understanding (if someone could take a minute to explain) is how i can cleanly tell jQuery listed to the dropdown and toggle these properly.

Here is my terrible jfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xFZuH/

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, those pesky jQuerys functions like `.click()` never work for me either.

Comment: "i never have luck with anything jquery .click, .change etc... always buggy." Are you wrapping those handlers in a `$(document).ready(function(){...})` block?

Comment: Yes i always wrap my jqeury in $(document).ready, even though i didn't in my jsfiddle

Comment: I think toggle is just going to switch it from it's last known state - so you can get things out of sync depending on how the user interacts with the form.  I'd dumb down the code and explicitly close all of the DIVs (style display:none) and then use a switch statement to select the one you want and open it up.

Comment: Yea that was my fallback, i was just hoping there's a cleaner less code intensive way of doing this.

Comment: You should look at backbone.js for something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty to fix your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xFZuH/1/

First, you have to figure out a way to map the values of the select options to the divs you want to show, in this case i chose to map them directly by ID

```
<select name="selection_group_1" id="selection_group_1" onChange="guests()">
    <option value="guestNames">0</option>
    <option value="guest1">1</option>
    <option value="guest2">2</option>
    <option value="guest3">3</option>
</select>
```

Then you should get a way to select all the divs you are manipulating at the same time, for that i gave them all the same class

```
<div id="guestNames" class="divsToToggle">
```

Then just capture the change event on the select, get the current selected value, hide all divs and show the div that matches the selected value

```
$('#selection_group_1').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $(".divsToToggle").hide();
    $("#"+id).show();
});
```

Ofcourse for reusability i would advice wrapping all this in a common parent so you can select only the divs you want, or adding the class of the divs to toggle to the select element on a data attribute, like:

```
<select id="bla" data-target=".divsToToggle">
    ....
</select>

....

$('#selection_group_1').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    var target = $(this).data("target");
    $(target).hide();
    $("#"+id).show();
});
```

Comment: This is good, but the logic is wrong. This way i only show each div by itself, however if someone chooses guest3, i need to show all 3 guest1,guest2 and guest3. However i see how you got this working so i'll try to tweak it as needed. Thanks!

Comment: in that case you may want to use a switch to toggle them, order the cases from higher to lower and dont break, ensuring that matching the first case will run all 3 cases, matching the second will run only 2, etc.